# CUDA 5.0 "Generate Relocatable Device Code" leads to invalid device symbol error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I am trying to do separate compilation using CUDA 5. For this reason I set the "Generate Relocatable Device Code" to "Yes (-rdc=true)" in Visual Studio 2010. The program compiles without errors, however, 
I get an invalid device symbol error when I try to initialize device constants using cudaMemcpyToSymbol.

i.e. I have the following constant

```
__constant__ float gdDomainOrigin[2];
```

and try to initialize it with

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(gdDomainOrigin, mDomainOrigin, 2*sizeof(float));
```

which leads to the error. The error does not occur, when I compile everything as a whole, without the aforementioned option set. Could anybody please help me with that?

Comment: Depending on your code structure, you [may need to use](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#code-changes-for-separate-compilation) `extern` or `static` to declare the visibility of the symbol.  You haven't given enough information about which modules are declaring the symbol and which modules are referencing them.

Comment: thank you for the response. Both code snippets above are in the same .cu file. Also, the symbol is only referenced in this file. However, I wanted to declare some kernels that used to be part of the .cu file using extern and define them in a different .cu file to make my code easier readable. However, these kernels do not access the symbol mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this. If build an application from two .cu files, one containing a __constant__ symbol and a simple kernel, and the other containing the runtime API incantations to populate that constant memory and call the kernel, it works *only when relocatable device code is enabled*, viz:

```
__constant__ float gdDomainOrigin[2];

__global__
void kernel(float *inout)
{
    inout[0] = gdDomainOrigin[0];
    inout[1] = gdDomainOrigin[1];
}
```

and

```
#include <cstdio>

extern __constant__ float gdDomainOrigin;
extern __global__ void kernel(float *);

inline 
void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char * file, int line, bool Abort=true)
{
    if (code != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n",
                             cudaGetErrorString(code),file,line);
        if (Abort) exit(code);
    }       
}
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

int main(void)
{
    const float mDomainOrigin[2] = { 1.234f, 5.6789f };
    const size_t sz = sizeof(float) * size_t(2);

    float * dbuf, * hbuf;

    gpuErrchk( cudaFree(0) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(gdDomainOrigin, mDomainOrigin, sz) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void **)&dbuf, sz) );

    kernel<<<1,1>>>(dbuf);
    gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );

    hbuf = new float[2];
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(hbuf, dbuf, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    fprintf(stdout, "%f %f\n", hbuf[0], hbuf[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running these in CUDA 5 on a 64 bit linux system with a Kepler GPU produces the following:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -o shared shared.cu shared_dev.cu 
$ ./shared 
GPUassert: invalid device symbol shared.cu 23

$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -rdc=true -o shared shared.cu shared_dev.cu 
$ ./shared 
1.234000 5.678900
```

You can see that in the first compilation, without relocatable GPU code generation, the symbol isn't found. In the second case, with relocatable GPU code generation, it is found, and the elf header in the object file looks just as you would expect:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -rdc=true -c shared_dev.cu 
$ cuobjdump -symbols shared_dev.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_30
code version = [1,6]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
identifier = shared_dev.cu

symbols:
STT_SECTION      STB_LOCAL    .text._Z6kernelPf
STT_SECTION      STB_LOCAL    .nv.constant3
STT_SECTION      STB_LOCAL    .nv.constant0._Z6kernelPf
STT_CUDA_OBJECT  STB_LOCAL    _param
STT_SECTION      STB_LOCAL    .nv.callgraph
STT_FUNC         STB_GLOBAL   _Z6kernelPf
STT_CUDA_OBJECT  STB_GLOBAL   gdDomainOrigin

Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_30
code version = [3,1]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
identifier = shared_dev.cu
ptxasOptions = --compile-only
```

Perhaps you could try my code and compilation/diagnostic steps and see what happens with your Windows toolchain.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and posting these example files, it helped me sorting out the problem! Actually my (stupid) mistake was to compile for compute capability 2.0 instead of 3.0